# How long does Essedum's effect last?

Tags: roma

In the game [Roma](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/16496/roma), the card Essedum reads:

> The defense value of the opponent's face-up cards is reduced by 2.

So the question is:

How long does this effect last?

Only for the current turn?

Or for the rest of the game?
If so, how are you supposed to keep track of the effected cards (since cards played later are not affected)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The card has an action dice symbol in the upper right.  This means that it takes one dice to activate the card and it is only in effect while it has a dice.  I'm not sure why you say "Cards played later are not affected".  For example, the Turris does not require a dice to be active, so it adds 1 to the defense of all the player's face-up cards for as long as it is in play, whether they were played before or after the Turris.